# Animating drawLine using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am animating `drawLine` as follows

```
val animateFloat = remember { Animatable(0f) }
LaunchedEffect(animateFloat) {
    animateFloat.animateTo(
        targetValue = 1f,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000, easing = LinearEasing))
}

Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize() ) {
    onDraw = {
        drawLine(
            color = Color.Black,
            Offset(size.width / 4, size.height / 6)
            Offset(size.width / 4, (size.height / 6 + SCAFFOLD_HEIGHT) * animateFloat.value),
            strokeWidth = 2f
        )
    }
}
```

This works absolutely fine. But when I add this inside a condition check, as follows,

```
if(lives == 5){
    drawLine(
        color = Color.Black,
        Offset(size.width / 4, size.height / 6)
        Offset(size.width / 4, (size.height / 6 + SCAFFOLD_HEIGHT) * animateFloat.value),
        strokeWidth = 2f
    )
}
```

Line is drawn, but fails to animate. Please let me know what might be happening under the hood.
`Compose_version = 1.0.0-beta04`

Comment: Which version of compose are you using?

Comment: Compose 1.0.0-beta04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve... But assuming that you want to animate just in case `lives == 5`, you just need to wrap the `LaunchedEffect` with your condition.
For instance:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LineAnimation(lives: Int) {
    val animVal = remember { Animatable(0f) }
    if (lives > 5) {
        LaunchedEffect(animVal) {
            animVal.animateTo(
                targetValue = 1f,
                animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000, easing = LinearEasing)
            )
        }
    }
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp, 200.dp)) {
        drawLine(
            color = Color.Black,
            start = Offset(0f, 0f),
            end = Offset(animVal.value * size.width, animVal.value * size.height),
            strokeWidth = 2f
        )
    }
}
```

and where you're calling this Composable, you can do the following:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AnimationScreen() {
    var count by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
        Button(onClick = { count++ }) {
            Text("Count $count")
        }
        LineAnimation(count)
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. For every count I want to draw a different line. Sure I will check how I can get that working.